# Autoforward is including the original mail as an attachment

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm working on a script to auto forward mail with custom message and attachment from original mail.

Code is running but one of the attachments is the original message like this:
[image: Example]

How do I remove it?

```vb
Option Explicit
Public Sub FW(olItem As Outlook.MailItem)

    With olItem
        .Attachments.Add olItem, olEmbeddeditem
        .Subject = "" & olItem.Subject
        .Body = "Hello there."
        .To = "someone@somewhere.com" ' <- update
        .Send
    End With

    '// Clean up
    Set olItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forward Email with its attachment in Outlook 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28840066/forward-email-with-its-attachment-in-outlook-2010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better off just using the `.Forward` method to create a forwarded version of the original email, as this automatically retains any attachments.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub FW(olItem As Outlook.MailItem)

    Dim olForward as Outlook.MailItem
    Set olForward = olItem.Forward

    With olForward
        .Subject = "" & olItem.Subject
        .Body = "Hello there."
        .To = "someone@somewhere.com" ' <- update
        .Send
    End With

    '// Clean up
    Set olItem = Nothing
    Set olForward = Nothing
End Sub
```