# Outlook vba - How can i add suffix on mail subject before forward, reply or replay to all?

Tags: vba, outlook

I need to forward or reply to a mail, then add suffix on subject, and send it.
thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share/post your current code?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.subject

Answer (score 0):

You could [reply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.MailItem.Reply(method)) or [replyAl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.MailItem.ReplyAll(even))l an email and add suffix to subject using the below code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ReplyMSG()
    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olReply As MailItem ' Reply
    Dim olRecip As Recipient ' Add Recipient

    For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
Set olReply = olItem.ReplyAll
olReplay.Subject = = olItem.Subject & “suffix”
    Set olRecip = olReply.Recipients.Add("Email Address Here") ' Recipient Address
        olRecip.Type = olCC
            olReply.HTMLBody = "Hello, Thank you. " & vbCrLf & olReply.HTMLBody
        olReply.Display

        'olReply.Send
    Next olItem
End Sub
```

Reference from:

[Outlook Reply or ReplyAll to an Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31817632/outlook-reply-or-replyall-to-an-email)

If you want to forward an email and add suffix to subject, please refer to the below code:

```
Sub ForwardEmail(item As Outlook.MailItem)
  Dim oMail As MailItem    

  On Error GoTo Release

  If item.Class = olMail Then
     Set oMail = item.Forward
     oMail.Subject = oMail.Subject & “suffix”
     oMail.HTMLBody = "Have a nice day." & vbCrLf & oMail.HTMLBody
     oMail.Recipients.Add "email address here"

     oMail.Save
     oMail.Send
  End If
 Release:
  Set oMail = Nothing
  Set oExplorer = Nothing
End Sub
```

Reference from:

[Forward Email with its attachment in Outlook 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28840066/forward-email-with-its-attachment-in-outlook-2010)

Answer (score 0):

Properly going to be hard, because depending on your hierarchy location you would only have a set number of rights and i do not think VB Macro would be allowed i know in many organizations here in Denmark VB Macros is a no no.

But you can create a Macro in the background where you grep Current mail and then alter the subject and then set it to when you press CTRL + R as you normally do when you reply but it might conflict so be careful because you might not want it on all emails. that you reply to.